# How to force all packets go through ssh tunnel?

Tags: proxy, ssh-tunnel

We have an SSH tunnel (`ssh -ND 127.0.0.1:8080 user@example.com`), that works fine for browsers if point them to `127.0.0.1:8080` as socks5 proxy, but other traffic is still not going through this tunnel.

How would i make absolutely all traffic go through SSH tunnel?

Any tools, settings i need for that?

The system i am using is Debian and MacOS so better if solution is more or less general for both platforms.

Comment: I think that you're searching for a VPN... ssh is (IMHO) not the right tool for this.

Comment: @UwePlonus VPN is not available in this case. Sure i am aware of OpenVPN and can set it up myself. But it is just not available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create VPN using ssh. Here is the relevant section from `man ssh`:

```
SSH-BASED VIRTUAL PRIVATE NETWORKS
    ssh contains support for Virtual Private Network (VPN) tunnelling using the tun(4) 
    network pseudo-device, allowing two networks to be joined securely.  The sshd_config(5)
    configuration option PermitTunnel controls whether the server supports this,
    and at what level (layer 2 or 3 traffic).

    The following example would connect client network 10.0.50.0/24 with remote network
    10.0.99.0/24 using a point-to-point connection from 10.1.1.1 to 10.1.1.2,
    provided that the SSH server running on the gateway to the remote network,
    at 192.168.1.15, allows it.

    On the client:

           # ssh -f -w 0:1 192.168.1.15 true
           # ifconfig tun0 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.252
           # route add 10.0.99.0/24 10.1.1.2

    On the server:

           # ifconfig tun1 10.1.1.2 10.1.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.252
           # route add 10.0.50.0/24 10.1.1.1
```

At the end, you will have tunnel interface which you can use to forward your traffic.

Comment: This is really cool! I've been using SSH tunnels for quite a while and never knew about this.